# Getting TCP data from iPhone

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

There is an application on the iPhone, this application forwards face data over TCP over the port to its iClone application
Through Wireshark I looked at what is being transmitted from the phone to the computer

[image: Image Wireshark]

And from the computer to the phone, I don’t know what it sends there, maybe what is connected

[image: Image Wireshark]

```
18 c0 4d 34 75 02 c2 2c 80 32 56 db 08 00 45 00  ..M4u..,.2V...E.
0010  02 72 00 00 40 00 40 06 de 55 ac 10 01 0b ac 10  .r..@.@..U......
0020  01 05 03 e7 c5 8d 2c e8 b3 6b 0a 28 cb 70 50 18  ......,..k.(.pP.
0030  20 00 00 ec 00 00 65 79 65 4c 6f 6f 6b 49 6e 5f    .....eyeLookIn_
0040  52 20 3a 20 31 33 2c 6d 6f 75 74 68 44 69 6d 70  R : 13,mouthDimp
0050  6c 65 5f 52 20 3a 20 34 2c 63 68 65 65 6b 53 71  le_R : 4,cheekSq
0060  75 69 6e 74 5f 4c 20 3a 20 34 2c 65 79 65 4c 6f  uint_L : 4,eyeLo
0070  6f 6b 49 6e 5f 4c 20 3a 20 30 2c 6a 61 77 52 69  okIn_L : 0,jawRi
0080  67 68 74 20 3a 20 30 2c 65 79 65 4c 6f 6f 6b 44  ght : 0,eyeLookD
0090  6f 77 6e 5f 4c 20 3a 20 30 2c 6e 6f 73 65 53 6e  own_L : 0,noseSn
00a0  65 65 72 5f 4c 20 3a 20 36 2c 6d 6f 75 74 68 46  eer_L : 6,mouthF
00b0  72 6f 77 6e 5f 52 20 3a 20 31 31 2c 6d 6f 75 74  rown_R : 11,mout
00c0  68 52 6f 6c 6c 4c 6f 77 65 72 20 3a 20 31 30 2c  hRollLower : 10,
00d0  6d 6f 75 74 68 53 74 72 65 74 63 68 5f 52 20 3a  mouthStretch_R :
00e0  20 31 36 2c 6d 6f 75 74 68 44 69 6d 70 6c 65 5f    16,mouthDimple_
00f0  4c 20 3a 20 34 2c 6d 6f 75 74 68 53 68 72 75 67  L : 4,mouthShrug
0100  55 70 70 65 72 20 3a 20 31 33 2c 62 72 6f 77 4f  Upper : 13,browO
0110  75 74 65 72 55 70 5f 52 20 3a 20 30 2c 6d 6f 75  uterUp_R : 0,mou
0120  74 68 4c 6f 77 65 72 44 6f 77 6e 5f 4c 20 3a 20  thLowerDown_L :
0130  31 31 2c 6d 6f 75 74 68 43 6c 6f 73 65 20 3a 20  11,mouthClose :
0140  32 31 2c 65 79 65 57 69 64 65 5f 52 20 3a 20 33  21,eyeWide_R : 3
0150  36 2c 6d 6f 75 74 68 50 72 65 73 73 5f 4c 20 3a  6,mouthPress_L :
0160  20 35 2c 6d 6f 75 74 68 52 6f 6c 6c 55 70 70 65    5,mouthRollUppe
0170  72 20 3a 20 38 2c 65 79 65 4c 6f 6f 6b 44 6f 77  r : 8,eyeLookDow
0180  6e 5f 52 20 3a 20 30 2c 6d 6f 75 74 68 46 72 6f  n_R : 0,mouthFro
0190  77 6e 5f 4c 20 3a 20 38 2c 62 72 6f 77 44 6f 77  wn_L : 8,browDow
01a0  6e 5f 4c 20 3a 20 32 2c 65 79 65 42 6c 69 6e 6b  n_L : 2,eyeBlink
01b0  5f 52 20 3a 20 30 2c 6d 6f 75 74 68 4c 65 66 74  _R : 0,mouthLeft
01c0  20 3a 20 33 2c 65 79 65 42 6c 69 6e 6b 5f 4c 20    : 3,eyeBlink_L
01d0  3a 20 30 2c 65 79 65 4c 6f 6f 6b 4f 75 74 5f 4c  : 0,eyeLookOut_L
01e0  20 3a 20 33 2c 62 72 6f 77 4f 75 74 65 72 55 70    : 3,browOuterUp
01f0  5f 4c 20 3a 20 30 2c 68 65 61 64 5f 55 70 20 3a  _L : 0,head_Up :
0200  20 32 39 2e 32 32 38 30 30 34 2c 68 65 61 64 5f    29.228004,head_
0210  4c 65 66 74 20 3a 20 30 2e 30 35 33 38 37 36 36  Left : 0.0538766
0220  34 36 2c 68 65 61 64 5f 52 69 67 68 74 54 69 6c  46,head_RightTil
0230  74 20 3a 20 37 2e 31 37 38 37 34 37 37 2c 48 65  t : 7.1787477,He
0240  61 64 50 6f 73 58 20 3a 20 30 2e 30 33 31 39 32  adPosX : 0.03192
0250  32 32 2c 48 65 61 64 50 6f 73 59 20 3a 20 30 2e  22,HeadPosY : 0.
0260  30 32 35 34 36 38 39 32 39 2c 48 65 61 64 50 6f  025468929,HeadPo
0270  73 5a 20 3a 20 30 2e 34 33 33 31 35 38 30 34 2c  sZ : 0.43315804,
```

But I just can't count. What I have:

```cs
static NetworkStream stream;
        static TcpClient client;
        static BinaryReader reader;
        static BinaryWriter writer;
        private const int port = 999;
        private const string server = "192.168.0.23";

        static void Main (string [] args)
        {
            ConStack ();
        }


static void ConStack ()
        {
            client = new TcpClient ();

            client.Connect (server, port); // client connection
            var stream = client.GetStream (); // returns a NetworkStream object
            reader = new BinaryReader (stream, Encoding.Unicode, false);
            writer = new BinaryWriter (stream, Encoding.Unicode, true);

            //writer.Write("JawOpen "); // When trying to send any message, the program flies into Exception and close program for iPhone| upd. Although I noticed that not all lines are crashed

            // start a new thread to receive data
            Thread receiveThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart (ReceiveMessage));
            receiveThread.Start (); // start stream
            Console.WriteLine ("Start Thread");
        }

  static void ReceiveMessage ()
        {
            byte [] data = new byte [1065]; // buffer for received data
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var byt = reader.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    builder.Append (Encoding.Unicode.GetString (data, 0, byt));
                    Console.WriteLine (builder.ToString ());
                 // I get emptiness
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Connection aborted! \ N {0}", ex.Message);
                    Console.ReadLine ();
                }
            }
        }
```

As a result, if I don't send a message, then I get blank lines and `reader.Read == 0`.

Comment: TCP is just a data stream ... you have to come up with a way to figure out when exactly one message is complete. Either by using a special separator character .. feasible for string based messages but bad for binary content ... or alternatively your phone application would need to prepend the expected message length to each message it sends so as the receiver you know exactly how many bytes you have to receive for one message ... both requires that the app on the phone fulfills the according protocol as well

Comment: Btw the first image (the second entry in Wireshark) is just your PC's response to the phone that a TCP package has successfully been delivered ;) That's why ist has no data, only a header. You are more interested in the data that comes in from the phone to the PC ;)

Comment: @derHugo [image packet](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2021/04/08/0017/0748/1159916/16/4fda291dde.png)

The bag is always of different lengths. Or rather, I scanned the packages and found that the package has a size from 612 to 1812
But this is again subjective. The size of the package depends on the data that is supplied in it.
In the package I want to get the face mesh from the iPhone program.

What I have provided screenshots is the interaction of the FACE LIVE program on the iPhone and the Realussion iClone program
ip 172.16.1.5 PC (iClone)
ip 172.16.1.11 iPhone

Comment: I have not tested my app and iPhone with Wireshark
And the screenshot shows that the package always ends the same
```HeadPosZ : 0.4320508,```

Comment: that trailing `,` to me rather looks like there is coming more in the next package ;)

Comment: @derHugo Here is a screenshot of how the application works on Iphone and my program
[Screen](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2021/04/08/0017/0748/1159916/16/d0e93a71d2.png)

The program on the iPhone does not send anything at all.
She's probably waiting for the chtoli signal?

But the app is still getting dummies.

Answer (score 0):

[Image new detail](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2021/04/09/0017/0748/1159916/16/496ce029a6.png)
After a lot of trying, I found one pattern.
When I first start connecting, iColne sends a 66B packet to the iPhone application.
iPhone, in turn, sends exactly the same packet 66 bytes long
This can be seen in the screenshot.

Only I just can't make out what's in the package.
I've tried it at home and at work.

Here are the results
result at work

```
iPhone_to_PC
0000   c2 2c 80 32 56 db 18 c0 4d 34 75 02 08 00 45 00   .,.2V...M4u...E.
0010   00 34 4e fc 40 00 80 06 00 00 ac 10 01 05 ac 10   .4N.@...........
0020   01 0b c4 8b 03 e7 f8 61 84 52 00 00 00 00 80 02   .......a.R......
0030   fa f0 5a 57 00 00 02 04 05 b4 01 03 03 08 01 01   ..ZW............
0040   04 02                                             ..


PC_to_iPhone
0000   18 c0 4d 34 75 02 c2 2c 80 32 56 db 08 00 45 00   ..M4u..,.2V...E.
0010   00 34 00 00 40 00 40 06 e0 93 ac 10 01 0b ac 10   .4..@.@.........
0020   01 05 03 e7 c4 8b 55 12 31 d4 f8 61 84 53 80 12   ......U.1..a.S..
0030   ff ff 49 c5 00 00 02 04 05 b4 01 03 03 05 04 02   ..I.............
0040   00 00                                             ..
```

result at Home

```
iPhone_to_PC
0000   72 4f 56 2b 8e 4d a8 a1 59 26 a3 af 08 00 45 00   rOV+.M..Y&....E.
0010   00 34 85 a6 40 00 80 06 f3 56 c0 a8 00 58 c0 a8   .4..@....V...X..
0020   00 1e eb 68 03 e7 07 69 b9 1a 00 00 00 00 80 02   ...h...i........
0030   fa f0 42 85 00 00 02 04 05 b4 01 03 03 08 01 01   ..B.............
0040   04 02                                             ..
           

PC_to_iPhone
0000   a8 a1 59 26 a3 af 72 4f 56 2b 8e 4d 08 00 45 00   ..Y&..rOV+.M..E.
0010   00 34 00 00 40 00 40 06 b8 fd c0 a8 00 1e c0 a8   .4..@.@.........
0020   00 58 03 e7 eb 68 74 34 8c 78 07 69 b9 1b 80 12   .X...ht4.x.i....
0030   ff ff 3d bc 00 00 02 04 05 b4 01 03 03 05 04 02   ..=.............
0040   00 00                                             ..
```

I could not figure out what the  [package is (screen)](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2021/04/09/0017/0748/1159916/16/92d3b54ba3.png)